# Ubuntu running slow and laggy

Tags: ati, cpu

My Ubuntu has been running pretty slow, but I don't know why. I have the latest updates and all. I installed Ubuntu i368 on a AMD processor does that effect the speed? 
Thank you.

Comment: You need to add more information about your hardware, free disk space, memory and exactly when does it get laggy?

Answer (score 1):

Very little information to go on here, but I'm going to take a shot at it anyway.  Normally when Ubuntu gets laggy for no obvious reason it has to do with gvfs-metadata.  This is particularly true if you've been moving files around a bit.  It's a pretty easy fix.  All you have to do is close Nautilus or whatever file browser you are running, open an terminal and type the following:

pkill gvfsd-metadata

then hit ENTER and when you get the prompt back, type:

rm -rf ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata

The first command stops the gvfsd process, and the second command erases gvfs-metadata file which often becomes corrupt or just too big.  Don't worry, though, a fresh new gvfs-metadata file is created as soon as the gvfsd process starts back up.  At the very least this does no harm and gives you a bit more speed / CPU usage.  The worst case scenario is that you see a bit of improvement.  The best case is that this fixes your problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you followed Blind Fish replied you may also would want to consider installing Preload, (adaptive readahead daemon) see here:https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=preload&op= read the description FYI....

Luis